# How can I style option hover background?

Tags: html, css, styles, html-select

I made select-option. But option:hover does not work. How can I fix it or what do you prefer? [Style must be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55MSm.png)

My codes

```
 <select>
      <optgroup label="Yaşayış üçün">
        <option>Yeni tikili</option>
        <option>Köhnə tikili</option>
      </optgroup>
      <optgroup label="Ticarət obyekti">
        <option>Yeni tikili</option>
        <option>Köhnə tikili</option>
      </optgroup>
    </select>
```

My styles Css

```
select {
  height: 48px;
  border: 1px solid #cbd5e1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  padding: 12px 16px;
}

optgroup {
  padding: 16px;
  background: #f1f5f9;
}

option {
  background-color: white;
}

option:hover {
  background: #dbeafe;
}
```

Comment: Styling for those base elements is very limited. Anything you put in CSS is going to be ignored by the browser. You would need to build your own select menu using custom js and css classes and either integrate them with the <select> and <options> or use something else like <input> and <li> . See the most recent answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-an-html-select-element?answertab=modifieddesc#tab-top or https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_custom_select

Comment: @AStombaugh I used w3school codes. But another problem is that optgroup does not work

Comment: If you read the entirety of the link I posted you can find that adding `<li class="dropdown-header">Dropdown header 1</li>` and `<li class="divider"></li>` can cosmetically divide your options into groups

Comment: @RahilAli <optgroup> is just as limited as the other tags. See the links I've provided as well as the links in the answers below for the workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

You can turn a `ul` into a drop-down menu and further style it that way. See example below:

> Source:
> https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_dropdowns.asp

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Dropdowns</h2>
  <p>The .dropdown class is used to indicate a dropdown menu.</p>
  <p>Use the .dropdown-menu class to actually build the dropdown menu.</p>
  <p>To open the dropdown menu, use a button or a link with a class of .dropdown-toggle and data-toggle="dropdown".</p>                                          
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this, because select is an system element. So use a HTML and CSS dropdown. You can style this.